# Changing the version or rails that my application is using

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed rails 3.0.1, when I try to do something like rails server i get the error message below.

note the first line saying it couldn't find rails gem 3.0.0.rc:
Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0.rc, runtime)' in any of the gem s
ources. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

How can I make my rails3 app use rails 3.0.1?

Thanks,

-p.s. the full error:

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:280:in
 `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0.rc, runtime)' in any of the gem s
ources. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/resol
ver.rb:162:in`start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/resol
ver.rb:131:in `block in resolve'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/resol
ver.rb:130:in`catch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/resol
ver.rb:130:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:153:in`resolve'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:93:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:137:in`specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:126:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/envir
onment.rb:23:in`requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:11:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler.rb:10
0:in`setup'
        from C:/Users/soheil/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/pakrat-rails3/c
onfig/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
        from :29:in `require'
        from script/rails:8:in`'

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile you can change this line :

gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

then run 
bundle install